# sendmail/qmail both run on the same server. Which used to send emails?

Tags: email, sendmail

sendmail and qmail both run on the same server. How can I know the which one is used to send email ?

I have a PHP application that sends email via the mail() function. The SMTP server it uses has both process running.
It is a server used for live applications, so I can't stop one process to do some tests.

Comment: I'd make sure that the machine really _is_ as you describe.  It's possible to get confused about these things, especially as most Unix/Linux MTSes have a `sendmail` program image file that is nothing whatsoever to do with the Sendmail software package.  There's almost never a need to set up a system in this way with two different MTS softwares running in parallel.  (Multiple instances of _one_ package is as exotic a configuration as things normally get.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to look in your `php.ini` file, under `[mail function]`. Here, the path to the mail sending binary is specified. Whatever is specified here, the `mail()` function in PHP will use.

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

The above one should be the default. So, if you haven't changed anything, PHP will use `sendmail`.

As [@JdeBP](https://superuser.com/users/38062/jdebp) mentions, you can also take a quick look at the headers of the mails received. If you look under the various `Received` sections, you will find some identification of the server software being used.

Comment: Some systems have `sendmail` as a symlink to the actual binary provided by the MTA, e.g. `sendmail.sendmail` or `sendmail.qmail`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Yeah, I'd trace down that one. Like your option though.

Comment: +1. The suggestion in [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) is to point `sendmail_path` directly at `qmail_inject`, which will be directly indicative with no further research.  But in the general case finding out whose binary `sendmail_path` is pointing to is the right answer for PHP on Unix/Linux.

Comment: While you're at it, you could mention in your answer that the `Received:` header fields in the received messages will yield very strong clues as to which software, Sendmail or qmail, processed the mail.  Sendmail and qmail write trace information in different forms.